# Stored procedure not working as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Am trying to create a stored procedure that will notify me if a username or email already exists in the table.
Here is the structure of my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`user_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`date_joined` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`user_category_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and here is the code for the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_account`( username_param VARCHAR(40),      email_param VARCHAR(60), pass VARCHAR(30), category_id TINYINT )
BEGIN 
DECLARE salt VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE username_var VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE email_var VARCHAR(60);

SELECT username_var INTO username_var FROM user WHERE username = username_param;
SELECT email_var INTO email_var FROM user WHERE email = email_param;

IF username_var = username_param THEN 
    SELECT 'username' AS message;
ELSEIF email_var = email_param THEN
    SELECT 'email' AS message;
ELSE 
    SET salt = '@4$^7EC%?';
    SET salt = CONCAT( username_param, salt );
    INSERT INTO user VALUES 
    ( DEFAULT, username_param, email_param, AES_ENCRYPT( pass, salt ), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, category_id );

    SELECT 'created' AS message;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Two problems:
**Problem 1:**
Everything works fine when inserting an unique entry in which has the username or email does not exist, but when the username or email does exist i get these errors in the screenshot below yet i expect the stored procedure to return a simple select indicating where the problem could be or indicated success as the in case when it returns 'created'
[image]

**Problem 2**
If it is a unique entry and it gets inserted into the table, the password column cell in that particular row gets inserted with an empty string.

What could be the cause of all the above? Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps these changes are what you are looking for. Changes to the schema, and your `if` blocks, and return values.

The return value is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` of the user id. Note, I pretty much followed your schema. Your Primary Key in that table could probably be collapsed a bit. Some might go lean with no user id or user name, but just the email address as the PK. Those are things to think about. I also added a unique key for email address.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `user_id` int auto_increment primary key,
    `username` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `password` varbinary(128) NOT NULL,
    `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `date_joined` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `user_category_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    unique key (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- truncate table user;
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
drop procedure if exists sp_create_account;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_account`
(   username_param VARCHAR(40),      
    email_param VARCHAR(60), 
    pass VARCHAR(30), 
    category_id TINYINT 
)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE salt VARCHAR(60);
    DECLARE username_var VARCHAR(40);
    DECLARE email_var VARCHAR(60);
    DECLARE recFound int;
    DECLARE foundStatus int DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT user_id INTO recFound FROM user WHERE username = username_param;
    IF recFound is null THEN
        SELECT user_id INTO recFound FROM user WHERE email = email_param;
        IF recFound is not null THEN
            SET foundStatus=1;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SET foundStatus=1;
    END IF;

    IF foundStatus=0 THEN 
        SET salt = '@4$^7EC%?';
        SET salt = CONCAT( username_param, salt );
        INSERT INTO user (username,email,password,active,date_joined,user_category_id) VALUES 
        ( username_param, email_param, AES_ENCRYPT( pass, salt ), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, category_id );
        set recFound=LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
    SELECT recFound;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test:**

```
call sp_create_account('Katherine','ksmith@hotmail.com','thepass01',101);
call sp_create_account('Katherine','ksmith@hotmail.com','thepass01',101);
call sp_create_account('Katherine','ksmith@hotmail.com','thepass01',101);
call sp_create_account('caspar','caspar001@gmail.com','thepass02',77);
select * from user;
+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+--------+---------------------+------------------+
| user_id | username  | email               | password         | active | date_joined         | user_category_id |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+--------+---------------------+------------------+
|       1 | Katherine | ksmith@hotmail.com  | _╦*Fó▄GàB╔┌O►²§' |      1 | 2016-07-13 17:56:54 |              101 |
|       2 | caspar    | caspar001@gmail.com | ♀½B§5U├↨I♀#*├ ∟L |      1 | 2016-07-13 17:57:09 |               77 |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+--------+---------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me a way to figure it out. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Your last ELSE needs to have all the commands you expect to execute in it enclosed in `BEGIN` ... `END`. Maybe? *I've been working more in MSSQL lately.*

Comment: could you help shade some more light on that

Comment: @kellymandem In MS SQL, if you want more than one statement in an IF or ELSE body, you have to surround them with `BEGIN` and `END` (in the same manner C languages use `{` and `}`). _It slipped my mind that MySQL handles it more like VB with if...then...endif_